# Are there any options that prevent anti-aliasing when saving png in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, export, png, antialiasing

I need to export figure from Matlab to PNG, but if the size of the matrix I display with `imshow` gets too "large", the output saved starts adding shades of color different from the original ones. Setting `opengl hardware` or `painter` as a renderer helps until for lower dimensions, but if the figure grows the problem is still there. I attached a sample code so you can check the output. It should have only magenta and white pixels, but when I check the resulting PNG I can see a lot of pink shades (anti-aliasing?). I don't know if it depends on the code or on the export setup.
I need 600x300 PNG.

DISCLAIMER: I'd really rather not have to use export_fig, thanks. I really appreciate your help.

```
brick=zeros(2300,2600,3,'uint8'); 
colonnebianche=randi(1550,[1000,1]);
righebianche=randi(1000,[400,1]);
brick(:,:,1)=165;
brick(righebianche,colonnebianche,1)=255;
brick(:,:,2)=35;
brick(righebianche,colonnebianche,2)=255;
brick(:,:,3)=99;
brick(righebianche,colonnebianche,3)=255;

loops=1;

for index=1:loops
    filenamearray=["face",index];
    loopfilename=strjoin(filenamearray,'_');
    imshow(brick);
    set(0, 'DefaultFigureGraphicsSmoothing', 'off')
    fig=get(groot,'CurrentFigure');
    fig.PaperUnits='points';
    fig.PaperPosition=[0 0 288 144];
    fig.GraphicsSmoothing = 'off';
    axis off;
    print(loopfilename,"-dpng","-painters");
    %saveas(fig,loopfilename,"png")
end
```

Comment: Could you attach the PNG output as well? It would help seeing what you see.

Comment: `get(groot,'CurrentFigure')` is just `gcf`.

Comment: You are only displaying an image. Don’t save images by displaying them and then exporting the figure window. Just write the image directly as a PNG. Use [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html).

Comment: use `export_fig` if you are adding MATLAB plotting stuff on top, it is really great.... but otherwise, follow @CrisLuengo's advice. Otherwise you are doing the equivalent of taking a photo of your computer monitor with a phone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a new user and still cannot attach PNG, but I will try to fix this. Imwrite seems to work indeed, but it does not respect the dimensions I set: I want a 600x300 pixels image, how could I get it with imwrite?Thanks for your help

Comment: `imresize` your image first, but then you are  interpolating, not keeping the original data.

Comment: Create an array of 300x600x3 elements (height x width x channels).

Comment: I cannot do this, I have to respect the starting dimensions I have set, otherwise I would have already done that. I will have even a larger matrix, keeping on the work.

Comment: You're telling us you have to respect the starting dimensions, but you also have to change the dimensions to something else for the PNG. These cannot coexist, either resize  the array (or create a new variable and resize that) to save it, or change the starting dimensions to match the desired final dimensions

Comment: I have to respect the starting dimensions and to obtain a 600 x 300 PNG, yes. If this cannot coexist, why I am obtaining this with my starting code? With the code I posted I am obtaining this, but with the dithering problem. With imwrite, I resolve the dithering but I get a different size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Interpolation="bilinear" Name/Value as part of image display with imshow, that includes anti-aliasing as part of the rendering pipeline.

```
 imshow(brick,Interpolation="bilinear")
```

Alternatively, you could consider using imresize and downsampling with whatever interpolant you want. By default, imresize uses anti-aliasing when you downsample for the "bilinear" and "bicubic" cases. If what you want is to export your image data at a particular grid size, imresize + imwrite is what I would do instead of relying on the graphics system to downsample if I understand your workflow correctly.

```
B = imresize(brick,[600 300]); % Bicubic + anti-aliasing on by default
imwrite(B,"yourOutputPNG.png");
```

Comment: In the end, I think I will accept the advice of using imwrite, even if it is not the exact solution I was looking for. Thank you all for your support